# Semicolon is missing while inserting SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Considering having this query:

```
String query="SELECT `Section` FROM `register` WHERE `Student Name` Like" "'?'";
```

I'm getting an **error** which is saying that:

> (';' expected)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this

```
String query = "SELECT Section FROM register WHERE Student Name Like '?'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like:

```
String query = "SELECT Section FROM register WHERE StudentName Like '?';";
```

Notice that a field name must be written as `StudentName` and not like: `Student Name`

Answer (score 0):

```
 String query="SELECT `Section` FROM `register` WHERE `StudentName` Like ?";
```

No space allowed in column names. should be `StudentName`.